# How to get all products from a specific category in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Im using node.js. I want to get products that belong in specific categories via **woocomerce api**.

I can't modify/add new php code, since this app is used by non programmers. They are supposed to just insert secret and key in an input field and me using those i start querying their shop programatically.

So questions similar to this: [Get Products by Product category in a shortcode with WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941982/get-products-by-product-category-in-a-shortcode-with-woocommerce) don't seem to apply to me.

**I'm interested to know what is the specific url endpoint i need to hit such that i can get all products from a given  category.**

Tried:

```
https://ecom.pssthemes.com/woocommerce/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=key&consumer_secret=secret&filter[product_cat]="decor"

https://ecom.pssthemes.com/woocommerce/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=key&consumer_secret=secret&filter[category]="decor"
```

and with the lib:

```
WooCommerce.get('products?filter[category]="decor"', function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

**none are not working.** This seems like a basic requirement. Am I missing something obvious here? Any insight into solving it is much appreciated. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, replacing `category id` with the id of the category you desire:

```
WooCommerce.getAsync('products?category=<category id>).then( (data) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```